# In Clojure, why do you have to use parenthesis when def'ing a function and use cases of let

Tags: clojure

I'm starting to learn clojure and I've stumbled upon the following, when I found myself declaring a "sum" function (for learning purposes) I wrote the following code

`(def sum (fn [& args] (apply + args)))`

I have understood that I defined the symbol sum as containing that fn, but why do I have to enclose the Fn in parenthesis, isn't the compiler calling that function upon definition instead of when someone is actually invoking it? Maybe it's just my imperative brain talking.

Also, what are the use cases of `let`? Sometimes I stumble on code that use it and other code that don't, for example on the Clojure site there's an exercise to use the OpenStream function from the Java Interop, I wrote the following code:

```
(defn http-get 
  [url] 
  (let [url-obj (java.net.URL. url)]
    (slurp (.openStream url-obj))))

(http-get "https://www.google.com")
```

whilst they wrote the following on the clojure site as an answer

```
(defn http-get [url]
  (slurp
    (.openStream
      (java.net.URL. url))))
```

Again maybe it's just my imperative brain talking, the need of having a "variable" or an "object" to store something before using it, but I quite don't understand when I should use `let` or when I shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer both of your questions:

1.

```
(def sum (fn [& args] (apply + args)))
```

Using `def` here is very unorthodox. When you define a function you usually want to use `defn`. But since you used `def` you should know that `def` binds a name to a **value**. `fn`'s return value is a **function**. Effectively you bound the name `sum` to the function returned by **applying** (using parenthesis which are used for application) `fn`.

You could have used the more traditional `(defn sum [& args] (apply + args))`

2.

While using `let` sometimes makes sense for readability (separating steps outside their nested use) it is sometimes **required** when you want to do something once and use it multiple times. It binds the result to a name within a specified context.

We can look at the following example and see that without `let` it becomes harder to write (function is for demonstration purposes):

```
(let [db-results (query "select * from table")] ;; note: query is not a pure function
    ;; do stuff with db-results
    (f db-results)
    ;; return db-results
    db-results)))
```

This simply re-uses a return value (`db-results`) from a function that you usually only want to run once - in multiple locations. So `let` can be used for style like the example you've given, but its also very useful for value reuse within some context.

Answer (score 1):

Both `def` and `defn` define a ***global*** symbol, sort of like a global variable in Java, etc.  Also, `(defn xxx ...)` is a (very common) shortcut for `(def xxx (fn ...))`.  So, both versions will work exactly the same way when you run the program.  Since the `defn` version is shorter and more explicit, that is what you will do 99% of the time.

Typing `(let [xxx  ...] ...)` defines a ***local*** symbol, which cannot be seen by code outside of the `let` form, just like a local variable (block-scope) in Java, etc.

Just like Java, it is optional when to have a local variable like `url-obj`.  It will make no difference to the running program.  You must answer the question, "Which version makes my code easier to read and understand?"  This part is no different than Java.